# I've Done The Quest, "Innocence Lost" and I've slept, but nothing has happened!

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've already completed the quest, and I've done nothing else wrong. I've slept after I finished it, but nothing happens.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: Did you already received a letter from Dark Brotherhood? A courrier will deliver it to you.

Comment: Sorry but you're going to need to provide more details for folks to be able to help you. Please provide the steps you took during the question, and what you expect to happen that hasn't happened.

Answer (score 3):

After killing Grelod, you must return to Aventus, and he'll give you a plate as payment (it's worth more than a regular plate). A courier will later deliver a mysterious note to you. You can tell it's from the DB by the response list coming up (something that never happens with the courier otherwise). After you get this note, sleep anywhere for any length of time, and you'll be transported to the Abandoned Shack, where your assassin career begins.

Comment: You must return to Aventus Aretino and tell him the deed is done. Then you get the letter, then you sleep etc.